# How to get a copy of the raw photo from the Mapillary app

Tags: web-mapping, android, mapillary

In Mapillary's documentation it says the photos are stored in the "app folder" before upload, and are deleted afterwards.  I have looked around the filesystem but can't find them.  I don't necessarily want to have to upload a photo to get a copy of it; and after upload, the raw photo isn't available anyway - it's already been overlaid with a "Mapillary" watermark.

details: I am using the Android client.

Answer (score 2):

you can find the current storage folder of the Mapillary Android app under Settings-> Developer in the app.

If you go there with a file explorer, you should be able to see the originals before they are uploaded.

Otherwise, clicking on an image in the approval view will open an image in the phones default picture viewer, from where you can save and share a single original.